# Python - Assign values from two lists to answer

Tags: python

I'm new to python!

```
players = ["Matt","Joe", "Barry","Billy"]
numbers = [1,2,3,4]

def assignment(players, numbers):
    for i in players:
        for j in numbers:
            print i,j
assignment(players,numbers)
```

My attempt is above.

I want to try make the answer =

```
Matt 1
Joe 2
Barry 3
Billy 4
```

but at the minute each name is being assigned each number! Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

use `zip`

```
players = ["Matt","Joe", "Barry","Billy"]
numbers = [1,2,3,4]

for a in zip(players, numbers):
    print(*a)
```

In the case where your lists are not the same length `zip` would only pair items that have a corresponding index in the other list, if you want the other items you can use `itertools.zip_longest` in python3 and specify a fillvalue for python to fill in the items that are empty, for Example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

players = ["Matt","Joe", "Barry","Billy", "Johnson", "Riyad"]
numbers = [1,2,3,4]

for a in zip_longest(players, numbers, fillvalue=0):
    print(*a)
```

Output

```
Matt 1
Joe 2
Barry 3
Billy 4
Johnson 0
Riyad 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def assignment(players, numbers):
    for i, j in zip(players, numbers):
        print i,j
```